# piping empty find result to du through xargs results in unexpected behavior

Tags: linux, find, xargs, du

I came up with a command to find files and print their sizes using find, xargs, and du.  I am having a problem when I search for something that does not exist.  Using the xargs method, du reports all the folders when something doesn't exist, but I expect it to report nothing because nothing should be found.  When using the -exec method it works correctly, but from what I have read and observed in bigger searches, it is less efficient because it repeats the du command for each file found instead of operating on the group of files found. See the section where it mentions -delete: http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/unix/findcmd.htm

Here is an example.  First, this is what is in the directories:

`ls

bar_dir/  test1.foo  test2.foo  test3.foo`

`ls bar_dir

test1.bar  test2.bar  test3.bar`

Here are two searches where I expect to find results:

`find . -name '*.foo' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 du -h

4.0K    ./test2.foo

4.0K    ./test1.foo

4.0K    ./test3.foo`

`find . -name '*.bar' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 du -h

4.0K    ./bar_dir/test1.bar

4.0K    ./bar_dir/test2.bar

4.0K    ./bar_dir/test3.bar`

Here is a search where I expect no results, but instead I get a listing of directories:

`find . -name '*.qux' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 du -h

16K     ./bar_dir

32K     .`

If I just use find, it returns nothing (as expected)

`find . -name '*.qux' -print0`

And if I use the -exec method for du, it also returns nothing (as expected)

`find . -name '*.qux' -type f -exec du -h '{}' \;`

So what is the matter with the xargs du method when find doesn't find anything?  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look at `du --files0-from -` ?

From `man du`

> ```
>    --files0-from=F
>           summarize disk usage of the NUL-terminated file names specified in file F; If F is - then read names from standard input
> ```

Try like this:

```
find . -name '*.qux' -type f -print0 | du -h --files0-from -
```

Comment: This works with a minor edit... Add a space between the `-I` and `{}`:  `find . -name '*.qux' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} du -h {}`  Thanks!   As a side note, I tried my original code without the `-print0` and `-0` and the directories were still returned. This code: `find . -name '*.qux' -type f -print | xargs du -h` still does not work.

Comment: This also works: `find . -name '*.qux' -type f -print0 | du -h --files0-from -`  I will read up on these two solutions.  Thanks again!

Comment: In my limited testing, it seems like the `--files0-from -` method is faster.